# Conditional expectation with three random variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

We have $N_1, N_2, N_3$ normally distributed random variables with $µ_i  =E[N_i]$, $σ_{ij}=Cov(N_i,N_j)$. We also have $\tilde{µ}_i=E[N_i|N_2 = x] $, $\tilde{σ}_{ij}=Cov(N_i,N_j|N_2 = x)$ and $v^2 =Var(N_1 - N_3|N_2 = x) = σ ̃_{11} - 2σ ̃_{13} + σ ̃_{33}$, where the tilde refers to the expectation conditioned by $N_2 = x$. All these are known.
 We want to find out $E[(e^{N_1} - N_2 e^{N_3})^+|N_2 = x]$.
 I started with $N_1 = aN_2 + bZ + c$ and $N_3 = dN_2 + eZ + f$, where Z is standard normal, and a,b,c,d,e,f are constants.
 In the article the answer is $e^{µ ̃_1+ 0.5 σ ̃_{11}} ϕ((µ ̃_1- µ ̃_3-log⁡x+ σ ̃_{11}-   
σ ̃_{13})/v) - x e^{µ ̃_3+ 0.5 σ ̃_{33}} ϕ((µ ̃_1- µ ̃_3-log⁡x+ σ ̃_{13}- σ ̃_{33})/v)$, where ϕ is the normal cumulative distribution function.
 I obtained 
 $e^{µ ̃_1+ 0.5 σ ̃_{11}} ϕ((µ ̃_1- µ ̃_3-log⁡x)/v) x e^{µ ̃_3+ 0.5 σ ̃_{33}} ϕ((µ ̃_1- µ ̃_3-log⁡x )/v)$.

I edited the post to show that the expectation takes into account only positive values, and to give more information.

Comment: This would be a very "good way to start"... Then adapt the solution to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/478309/).

Comment: I think you can solve the problem yourself. When you express $N_1$ and $N_3$ as linear combinations of $N_2$ and $Z$, why do you assume that it is the same $Z$ for both of them? Btw, you should explicitely state that you want $Z$ to be independent of $N_2$. In general, such a representation with the same $Z$ does not exist, because it would imply that the covariance matrix of $N_1,N_2,N_3$ has only rank two. But you can do it with two independent standard normals $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, independent of $N_2$.

Comment: I have completed the verification and the correct answer is the first one.